# Xcode doesn't Archive last version of app

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, archive, ipa

I build an application and I use Ad Hoc distribution. I have a problem generating a **ipa** from an application. The application **compiles** just fine and even **works in the simulator** with the current version. When I trying to compile from the **archive** it generate a **ipa** from last version of my app. I already **clean & build** more than 100 times and nothing change.

Comment: 1. How do you know which version it's creating the .ipa from? I've never seen Xcode use a version other than the one that you select in the organizer. 2. Have you tried deleting the app from your test device before installing the new .ipa?

Comment: I know because the listener to the uibutton still the same and my view also. I try also to delete on device and nothing change. I think the problem came from the archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help. I check my `.plist` and the problem was there. **I was trying to download my app from local where my** `.plist` link **ipa** to the web server. That why i download an old version.